# sort json properties in descending order

Tags: json

I have the following json, how can I sort the "c" value in DESC order?

```
[{"id":"2","val":"2pm.com","c":"4"}, 
{"id":"2","val":"Adidas","c":"2"},
{"id":"2","val":"AJ Morgan","c":"2"},
{"id":"2","val":"Alfio Raldo","c":"3"},
{"id":"1","val":"ASOS","c":"112"},
{"id":"2","val":"ASOS","c":"34"},
{"id":"2","val":"ASOS Curve","c":"39"},
{"id":"2","val":"Baby Be Dazzled","c":"13"}]
```

I use PHP and ajax

Comment: you should be sort `array` in php after that `json_encode` sorted array and send in ajax response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something in JS like,

```
arr.sort(compare);

function compare(obj1, obj2) {
    return obj1.c - obj2.c;
}

console.log(arr);
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qd9Rm/)